# cypress .next at end of list yields '' but I need to break instead

Tags: list, testing, cypress, each, break

I am writing Cypress tests for an application that has a dynamic group/list of items. Each item has a details link that when clicked creates a popup with said details. I need to close that popup and move to the next item in the group.

I first tried to use the `.each()` command on the group and then would `.click({multiple:true})` the details but the popup would cover the the next click. Adding `{foce:true}` does allow all of the popups to display but I don't think that is in the spirit of how the application should function.

My latest attempt has been to create a custom command using `.next()` to iterate through the group. This works but when `.next()` reaches the end of the group it yields `""` and so the test ultimately fails.
The actual error I get is:
``` Expected to find element: ``, but never found it. Queried from element: <div.groups.ng-star-inserted> ```

the `.spec.ts`

```
describe('Can select incentives and view details', () => {
  it('Views incentive details', () => {
    cy.optionPop('section#Incentives div.groups:first')
  })
})
```

the `index.ts`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('optionPop', (clickable) => {
    
    cy.get(clickable).find('[ng-reflect-track="Estimator, open_selection_dial"]').click()
    cy.get('mat-dialog-container i.close').click()
    cy.get(clickable).next().as('clicked').then(($clicked) => {
        //fails at .next ^ because '' is yielded at end of list
        cy.wrap($clicked).should('not.eq','')
    })
    cy.optionPop('@clicked')
})
```

Comment: Please share the HTML of your list elements.

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `cy.optionPop()` inside of itself? On a base reading, this recursion would make the command continuously run until it hits an error.

Comment: The `.click({multiple:true})` will click on all the, presumably, links which will have all the popups appear at once. That looks like flaw in the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have the right idea, but it might work better in a plain JS function rather than a custom command.

```js
function openPopups(clickables) {

  if (clickables.length === 0) return   // exit when array is empty

  const clickable = clickables.pop()    // extract one and reduce array

  cy.wrap(clickable)
    .find('[ng-reflect-track="Estimator, open_selection_dial"]').click()

  cy.get('mat-dialog-container i.close')
    .should('be.visible')                // in case popup is slow
    .click()

  // wait for this popup to go, then proceed to next
  cy.get('mat-dialog-container')
    .should('not.be.visible')        
    .then(() => {
      openPopups(clickables)   // clickables now has one less item
    })        
}

cy.get('section#Incentives div.groups')  // get all the popups
  .then($popups => {
    const popupsArray = Array.from($popups)  // convert jQuery result to array
    openPopups(popupsArray)
  })
```

---

Some extra notes:

- Using `Array.from($popups)` because we don't know how many in the list, and want to use `array.pop()` to grab each item and at the same time reduce the array (it's length will control the loop exit).
- `clickables` is a list of raw elements, so `cy.wrap(clickable)` makes the individual element usable with Cypress commands like `.find()`
- `.should('be.visible')` - when dealing with popup, the DOM is often altered by the click event that opens it, which can be slow relative to the speed the test runs at. Adding `.should('be.visible')` is a guard to make sure the test is not flaky on some runs (e.g if using CI)
- `.should('not.be.visible').then(() => ...` - since you have some problems with multiple overlapping popups this will ensure each popup has gone before testing the next one.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.